# What is the correct syntax for my C# query. It needs to reference a variable named "x"

Tags: c#, string

Ok guys I think this is a pretty simple one, I just don't know the answer myself. I have this query which is as follows

```
var qry ="/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq " + x ;
```

The `x` is a string which is constantly chaning but the syntax requires the string which the query is using to filter must be in ' ' so this would work

```
var qry ="/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq 'Hello' ";
```

I understand I can change the string to get the first ' in by doing this

```
var qry ="/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq '" + x ;
```

But I don't know how to get the final ' after I have declared the + x string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of query syntax are you using? Adding a tag for that might be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var qry ="/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq '" + x +"'";
```

or

```
var qry = String.Format("/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq '{0}'", x);
```

Comment: No that doesnt work it just keeps telling me there is a ; expected

Comment: Oh no i didn't see the + infront of the "'"! 

Cheers mate ur a star, I knew it would be something easy

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already know how to add string to a string, why not use that again?

```
var qry = "/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq '" + x + "'";
```

Another option is to use `string.Format()`:

```
var qry = string.Format("/tblEACNumbers?$filter = EACNumber eq '{0}'", x);
```

Both of those options are vulnerable to injection attacks, so you should add some escaping, depending on where you send this query. You don't have to worry about this if `x` comes from a trusted source, though.